# Elastic query by time for the current day

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query which gets all the data for the dates that I set. This query works very well so far.

When I remove the date and change the format I thought that elastic will take the current day but don't.

```
**GET /BLA*/_search**
{
  "size" : 1,
  "sort" : "@timestamp",
  "_source" : ["@timestamp", "details"],
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {"term" : {"FIELD" : "TRUC"}},
        {"regexp" : { "details" : ".*TRUC.*" }},
        {"range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
            "from": "2020-05-05 07:00",
            "to": "2020-05-05 07:30",
            "time_zone" : "Europe/Paris"
          }
        }}
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to remove the date and change the format but it doesn't work.
an idea? The goal is to take the data for the current day.

```
**GET /BLA*/_search**
{
  "size" : 1,
  "sort" : "@timestamp",
  "_source" : ["@timestamp", "details"],
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {"term" : {"FIELD" : "TRUC"}},
        {"regexp" : { "details" : ".*TRUC.*" }},
        {"range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "format" : "HH:mm",
            "from": "07:00",
            "to": "07:30",
            "time_zone" : "Europe/Paris"
          }
        }}
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR not possible. The only [way I know of](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) to work w/ relative datetimes in range queries is the following:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "sort": "@timestamp",
  "_source": [
    "@timestamp",
    "details"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-2h",
              "lte": "now+3h",
              "time_zone": "Europe/Paris"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but it's all relative to `now`.

---

Here's the explanation of why your query doesn't *seem* to work.

Let's set up an index whose `@timestamp` will be of the format `HH:mm`:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "HH:mm"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then ingest a doc

```
POST my_index/_doc
{
  "@timestamp": "07:00"
}
```

all nice and dandy. Now let's investigate what the *actual* indexed date is:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "ts_full": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
                  LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                     Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['@timestamp'].value.millis),
                     ZoneId.of('Europe/Paris')
                  ).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which yields

```
"01/01/1970 08:00:00"
```

since Paris is UTC+1.

### So summing up, you can surely index & search by 'dates' (strictly speaking 'times') of the format `HH:mm` but they're all going to pertain to Jan 1 1970.

Answer (score 0):

**Querty for getting today's documents**

```
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now/d",
              "time_zone": "UTC"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```